# Can't remap Ctrl key with xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

My laptop keyboard doesn't have a <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> key. And I use a different layout than the native layout of my keyboard, so there are some keys that do nothing. So I'm trying to remap one of those keys to use as a <kbd>Right Control</kbd>. I'm doing the following command: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 97=Control_R'`.
I also tried with <kbd>Control</kbd>_<kbd>L</kbd>. But the key do nothing. 
Then I tested with Alt key:
`xmodmap -e 'keycode 97=Alt_r'`
and it works fine.

Why can't I remap the control key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the mapping of the control key is a two step process. The first part is to get the right information for the *keycode* and *keysym*. The second part is to make sure the modifier mapping is right.

It sounds like you've got the correct keycode already so try this instead. Create a file **myxmodmap** with the following

```
clear control
keycode 97 = Control_R
add control = Control_R Control_L
```

Now process the file with xmodmap

```
[~]$ xmodmap myxmodmap
```

If you want those xmodmap expressions to be processed each time you log in change the file name to *~/.Xmodmap*

Comment: TIL why everybody keeps recommending kbd :)