# How can I remap my keys to act like the Macintosh keyboard (like hold alt l + l click = r click)?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac, xmodmap

I want my keyboard layout to act like a Macintosh keyboard. It's hard to use my computer after years on a mac.

I want to disable my `right mouse click`, and replace it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `right mouse click`.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key will also act like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

I want my <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> to be the `HUD` key.

I still want my <kbd>Super</kbd> key to be the same.

Can someone please make a script, or point me in the direction of a program to do all this with ease. If you were to make a script/whatever, can you please make one what will reverse all keyboard changes in-case I feel that it is not the same. I will add to the post if I miss anything.

Thank you.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean with 'alt key will act like ctrl'? Do you want to rebind alt to ctrl?

Comment: @rakete eg. i do ctrl+c for copy. I want alt+c for copy instead of ctrl. I want to switch ctrl and alt. plus do everything i mentioned above.

Comment: swapping ctrl and alt could be done with xmodmap, it is actually pretty easy but maybe its better you'd ask it again in a seperate question, or take a look at already answered questions if they help you, e.g.: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93950/cant-remap-ctrl-key-with-xmodmap

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool xte to send mouseclicks or keypresses to the X server from the command line. And if you bind that with xbindkeys to alt and left mouse button, then you should have what you want.

First install neccessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
```

then create the ~/.xbindkeys config file with the following content:

```
"xte 'mouseclick 3'"
  Alt + b:1
```

That should run "xte 'mouseclick 3'", which sends a right click to the X server, everytime you press alt + left mouse.

Start the daemon to make it work (use -n for nodaemon mode if you are testing things, so you can easily kill it with Ctrl-C, start without -n to run it in the background):

```
xbindkeys -n
```

The sad news is though: it doesn't work. It should, but for me on Ubuntu 12.04 running Unity/Compiz, it does not work, xbindkeys can't intercept mouse button presses. Still, maybe you are luckier or have a config where xbindkeys is able to intercept mouse button presses.

Comment: here is another guy having problems with xbindkeys and mouse buttons: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31257/xbindkeys-cannot-listen-to-mouse-button-click-for-a-macro

Answer (score 0):

In System Settings, you got two places for options about your keyboard :

- `Keyboard Layout` to configure the layout of your keyboard (qwerty, azerty, Macintosh, BEPO, ...).
- `Keyboard` to configure shortcuts on your keyboard (and your keyboard responsiveness too).

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn’t work perfectly unfortunately.